# Covering a finite collection intervals

Tags: real-analysis

I was trying to solve one of the problems in stein's real analysis book
Suppose $I_1, I_2, . . . , I_N$ is a given finite collection of open intervals in R. Then there are two finite sub-collections $I^{'}_1,I^{'}_2,...,I^{'}_K$ , and$I^{′′}_1,I^{′′}_2,...,I^{′′}_L$, so that each sub-collection consists of mutually disjoint intervals and

$\bigcup_{j=1}^N I_j=\bigcup_{k=1}^K I_k^{'}\cup\bigcup_{l=1}^KI^{''}_l$

I followed the hint given by Stein:

Choose $I_1^{′}$ to be an interval whose left end-point is as far left as possible. Discard all intervals contained in $I_1^{′}$ . If the remaining intervals are disjoint from $I_1^{′}$ , select again an interval as far to the left as possible, and call it $I_2^{′}$ . Otherwise choose an interval that intersects $I_1^{′}$ , but reaches out to the right as far as possible, and call this interval $I_1^{′'}$. Repeat this procedure.

It seems pretty obvious to me that the claim is true. However, I find it hard to formalize everything. Could someone point to me how to formalize this?